# I want to access dynamic value in VirtualService for uri

Tags: kubernetes, routes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, gateway

I want to deploy two services with different URLs.

```
 - match:
      uri:
        prefix: /pune
    route:
    - destination:
        host: wagholi
        port:
          number: 8080
 - match:
      uri:
        prefix: /pune/{location}
    route:
    - destination:
        host: yerwada
        port:
          number: 8080
 - match:              
      uri:
        prefix: /pune/{local}/here
    route:
    - destination:
        host: hadapsar
        port:
          number: 8080
```

In this scenario, When I am hitting API getting 404 Not Found /pune/yerwada when I pass location value as yerwada. Also  I am passing /pune/hadapsar/here getting same error 404 Not Found /pune/hadapsar/here, When I pass hadapsar at the place of local. !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do the requests pass in a header named `location` with value of `pune`? If "no" then remove this from the matching rules - it is the cause for the requests not being matched by `uri` prefix alone:

```
    - headers:
        location:
          exact: pune
```

Just in case, here is a link to the [relevant doc](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPMatchRequest).

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

We can go with regex for uri.

```
 - match:
      uri:
        prefix: /pune
    route:
    - destination:
        host: wagholi
        port:
          number: 8080
 - match:
      uri:
        regex: \/pune/\/(.+)
    route:
    - destination:
        host: yerwada
        port:
          number: 8080
 - match:              
      uri:
        prefix: \/pune\/(.+)\/here
    route:
    - destination:
        host: hadapsar
        port:
          number: 8080
```